# How to print the individual element value of an interface in Golang

Tags: go, tensorflow

I have a piece of code which returns a [][]float32 value with a shape of [1,2]. Below is the code snippet.

```
  result, runErr := model.Session.Run(
        map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
            model.Graph.Operation("x").Output(0): tensor,
        },
        []tf.Output{
            model.Graph.Operation("predict").Output(0),
        },
        nil,
  )
  fmt.Println(result[0].Value())
```

The output of the following code is:

```
[[0 1]]
```

I need to access the individual elements 0 and 1, however when I try to fetch it using the following `fmt.Println(result[0].Value()[0][0])` it results in an error:

> (type interface {} does not support indexing)

How can I access the individual elements for my processing?

Comment: Because indexing on interface is not possible. Get underlying type of interface using assertion and then get the value on index.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet for the same?

Comment: There are numerous questions and and answers here with that exact error message. What are you asking that isn't covered already?

Comment: @Vasanti get type of `result[0].Value()` using reflection as `fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(result[0].Value()))`. and then type assert that to get value

Comment: @Himanshu: a tip for quickly checking the type of things, use `fmt.Printf` with `%#v` or  `%T`.

Answer (score 1):

Using type assertion, we can fetch the individual values by its index

`md := result[0].Value().([][]float32)
fmt.Println(md[0][0])
fmt.Println(md[0][1])`